# Ionic 3 blank app fails to build to Android when Background Geolocation plugin added

Tags: ionic3

I have an old ionic v3 project with a load of plugins installed and it works, but with a brand new ionic v3 'testplugins' project I cannot get it to build to Android with the background geolocation plugin at all!

There are the steps I've done to create this problem in ionic v3 ...

```
ionic start test blank --type=ionic-angular
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android
```

This builds successfully, but now install the background geolocation plugin.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation@alpha
ionic cordova build android
```

This fails with the following error ...

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  testplugins\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\authenticator.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/icon (aka io.ionic.starter:mipmap/icon) not found.

  error: failed linking file resources.
```

I can confirm that the drawable and mipmap files exist in the folder platforms\android\app\src\main\res\

I've tried changing @mipmap/icon to @mipmap/ic_launcher with no success like other blogs say to try.

package.json

```
        "GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11+",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "26+",
        "ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
        "SMALL_ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
        "ACCOUNT_NAME": "@string/app_name",
        "ACCOUNT_LABEL": "@string/app_name",
        "ACCOUNT_TYPE": "$PACKAGE_NAME.account",
        "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": "$PACKAGE_NAME"
      }
```

Nothing got added to my config.xml and this seems to be the case for some other plugins I've used lately. Is this right?

I have manually added this to config.xml ...

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="~3.0.0-alpha.50">
        <variable name="GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11+" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION" value="26+" />
        <variable name="ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
        <variable name="SMALL_ICON" value="@mipmap/icon" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_NAME" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_LABEL" value="@string/app_name" />
        <variable name="ACCOUNT_TYPE" value="$PACKAGE_NAME.account" />
        <variable name="CONTENT_AUTHORITY" value="$PACKAGE_NAME" />
    </plugin>
```

I'm sure when I installed a plugin a  entry automatically added to config.xml. Is this no longer needed?

What do I need to do to get the build working with the background geolocation plugin?

Any help welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the android platform android folder and build again. If the error still  there, try to add platform android again.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've tried various combinations of removing and installing android and the plugin and still the issue persists. Any ideas on how to resolve the mipmap/icon issue?